# WPF DataGrid repaints all the time

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm adding multiple elements to an ObservableCollection binded to a DataGrid from another process. I've tried to add elements one by one, and using a custom ObservableCollection to add a range like this:

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
{
    foreach (var item in range)
        this.Items.Add(item);

    this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
    this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
    this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

Using the AddRange method the UI freezes a lot (it's completely unusable while adding items), probably because of the reset event. Using the WPF Performance Profiling Tools I see that the DataGrid repaints completely all the time, even with virtualization. I'm using the following code in the DataGrid to activate the virtualization:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

Trying to use a normal ObservableCollection and adding one by one is better but still repaints with each item even if its not visible and is still slow, the frame rate halves.

Is there something I'm missing to make the performance better? It's possible for the DataGrid to not repaint everything when adding item/s (that its/are supossed to be invisible and not "painted" because of virtualization)?

Comment: can you tell me if this helps: detach your collection from your DataGrid.ItemsSource and then add items, and then attach it again

Comment: The thing is, there is a process that reads an event log from a device via USB. That process can take, depending of the number of events, seconds or even minutes to complete. The collection has a custom sort so while its reading we want to see if something new is added (and may be shown if the sort put the new row in the visible space), so detaching and attaching again is not a solution.

Comment: Please provide a minimal repo of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Maybe you have disabled the virtualization somehow. It's impossible to say based on the information you have provided.

Comment: How often are you adding items?  It looks like you're doing it in batches, which is good (in theory), but how often are you calling `AddRange`?  How large is a typical batch, and how large is the target collection usually?  Are you binding directly to the `ObservableCollection`, or are you using a `CollectionViewSource` as an intermediary?

Comment: everytime he calls Items.Add, the collection is going to raise this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);, which causes the wpf to repaint. virtualization doesnt really help here, right? i think he needs to modify the collection so that the collectionchanged is raised only after he added all his items, or do i not understand something?

Comment: @Milan The inner `Items` collection is just a `List<T>`; adding to it will not trigger change events.